# Top tags missing one where I've only posted one answer

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page

[In my profile my top three tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044866/peilonrayz?tab=profile) all come from the same answer. I've gotten no upvotes on the other answers, to the same tags.

[My tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044866/peilonrayz?tab=tags) shows JavaScript just fine.

---

<sub>So you don't have to look at my profile.</sub>

My top tags:

[image: Top tags]

My tags:

[image: My tags]